# DIDiskQuotaUser leaking file handles

Tags: c#, windows

I made a application to check the quota space checking application its done like this

```
DIDiskQuotaUser QuotaInfo = null;
try
{
    QuotaInfo = this.gDiskQuotaControl.FindUser(SAMUser);
}
catch
{
    QuotaInfo = null;
}
```

Defenition of FindUser

```
[DispId(1610743828)]
public virtual DIDiskQuotaUser FindUser(string LogonName);
```

Comes from:

```
[TypeLibType(2)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces("DiskQuotaTypeLibrary.DIDiskQuotaControlEvents")]
    [Guid("7988B571-EC89-11CF-9C00-00AA00A14F56")]
    [ClassInterface(0)]
    public class DiskQuotaControlClass : DIDiskQuotaControl, DiskQuotaControl, DIDiskQuotaControlEvents_Event, IDiskQuotaControlEvents, DIDiskQuotaUser, IEnumerable
```

Problem is that the loop is leaking file handles on the server im checking, and i cant see any way to dispose te return from FindUser

Comment: Off-topic: The catch clause is redundant. If an exception occurs during expression evaluation (the method call or call attempt), the assignment cannot happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try calling [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx) on the object.  That should be the equivalent of calling Release on the COM object until its reference count is zero, which should dispose of the object and release its handle.

Comment: Seems to have fixed it. Thanks for you help